# Data transfer rates for iOS

Tags: ios5, tcp

We are developing a application that transfers data from iOS to a server.

On our latest test the upload speed at both the beginning and end of the transfer was .46 Mbps and the ammount of data transfer was 14.5 MB. That should take about 4 minutes according to the math. It took 6 minutes and 19 seconds. Is that a standard ammount of time for that data to be transfered? Or is this an issue with the coding?

Comment: Are you uploading the data over a satellite connection or something?  That's crazy slow.

Comment: I'm confused. If you transferred 14.5 MB at 0.46 Mb/s, the transfer took about 4.2 minutes. It *didn't* take 6.2 minutes. Or if it did, then either your transfer rate or data size is incorrect. As for whether that's too long, well it's slow for broadband, but fast for 2G.

Comment: Satellite, 2G, same difference :-)

Comment: If you're having a problem with your program, you should post relevant code.

Comment: The data rates were tested using speed test app. I'll try the tcp dump.

Comment: The transfer did take 6 min 20 sec when it should have been faster based on those rates.

Answer (score 0):

You can lose 3-15% in TCP overhead, and that's before you account for any packet retransmission due to errors or packet loss.  Your actual transmission time is enough to indicate that you probably are experiencing delay in data transmission related to more than just TCP overhead.  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Performance/Nagle/summary.html is one good reference for some detailed metrics on TCP overhead.

You should run a tcpdump on the server side to get a more accurate picture of what's occurring.